# DICOM TLS between Orthanc and pynetDicom fails with error ErrorDetails: DicomAssociation - connecting to AET "MY_AET": TLS error: OpenSSL error

Tags: openssl, tls1.2, pynetdicom, orthanc-server, python-ssl

I am trying to create a secure communication between Orthanc(client on my local (Mac)) and pynetDicom(server on my EC2). For this I obtained X.509 certificate from Lets Encrypt. I have added the certs to pynetDicom like this in the pythons ssl context

```
# Set up TLS
context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=CERT_FILE, keyfile=KEY_FILE, password=None)

# If a certificate chain file is needed
context.load_verify_locations(cafile=CHAIN_FILE)

ae.tls_server_context = context

assoc = ae.start_server(
    (NODE_IP, NODE_PORT),
    ae_title=AE_TITLE,
    evt_handlers=handlers,
    ssl_context=ae.tls_server_context  # Enable TLS
)
```

I tried testing the TLS connection with openssl and it works with `-partialChain` tag, with an error at the end:
openssl s_client -connect pacs.avendahealth.com:443 -CAfile /Users/sumitjanawlekar/pynetDicom_cert/fullchain.pem -partial_chain with

```
 Start Time: 1695710162
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
80208DF401000000:error:0A000126:SSL routines:ssl3_read_n:unexpected eof while reading:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:304:
```

Without the partialChain tag it fails with error

```
Start Time: 1695710953
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 2 (unable to get issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
---
80208DF401000000:error:0A000126:SSL routines:ssl3_read_n:unexpected eof while reading:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:304:
```

When I try sending Dicom data from Orthanc, it fails with this reason.

```
ErrorCode: 9
ErrorDescription: Error in the network protocol
ErrorDetails: DicomAssociation - connecting to AET "MY_AET": TLS error: OpenSSL error
```

I am new to this, how can I make this work?

PSA: the connection works fine as I turn off TLS. Also the request flows like this DICOM Client -> aws network load balancer (NLB) -> Ec2(pynetDicom running here).
I even tried terminating TLS at the NLB level, still same error

I have tried TLS termination, encryption at pynetDicom level, I even tried local setup (client and server both as Orthanc running on local), testing with tools like openssl etc. All did not work.

Comment: Have you tried enforcing the maximum TLS version? pynetdicom doesn't support v1.3:  `context.maximum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2`

Comment: @scaramallion I tried your solution, but still the same error. Orthanc logs prints this 
`Error in the network protocol: DicomAssociation - connecting to AET "UNFOLD_AI": TLS error: OpenSSL error`

I tried setting up a HTTPS connection (not related to DICOM) with the same certificates to make sure my certificates and way of implementation were not flawed and this worked fine.
Again DICOM trasferì works without TLS